# Python - Flask assets fails to compress my asset files

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

noob here. I was trying to crunch my javascript files using [flask assets](http://elsdoerfer.name/docs/flask-assets/) but unfortunately my view rendered all the javascript files as **separate links** and not as **one** minified file.

Here is my code and file structure. Please help me learn.

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.assets import Environment , Bundle
from main.views import main
from webassets.loaders import PythonLoader

app = Flask(__name__)
assets = Environment(app)

app.register_blueprint(main, url_prefix='/')

#Compress All Assets
js = Bundle('javascripts/main.js',
            'javascripts/plugins.js',
            'javascripts/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js',
            'javascripts/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js',

            filters='jsmin', output='gen/packedjs.js')
assets.register('js_all', js)

css = Bundle('stylesheets/css/main.css',
            'stylesheets/css/normalize.css',
            filters='sass,less,cssmin', output='gen/packedcss.css')
assets.register('css_all', css)
```

This is my code in index.html

```
{% assets "css_all" %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ ASSET_URL }}">
{% endassets %}

{% assets "js_all" %}
       <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ ASSET_URL }}"></script>
{% endassets %}
```

My file structure of css and javascript files.

- static

  - gen (folder)
- Javascript (folder)

  - javascript file 1
  - javascript file 2
  - javascript file 3

Comment: Maybe you are running in debug mode, which disables the minification?

Answer (score 7):

To fix this problem install jsmin manually. Just do as follow:

```
pip install jsmin
```

Or as you will:

```
easy_install jsmin
```

I hope i've helped you. Be happy!

Comment: The Flask Assets documentation apparently just leaves that part out.

Comment: install `cssmin` while you're at it, good article here: https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-assets/